# Did my reopen vote get counted properly (after network glitch)?

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

A few hours ago, I went into the Super User Reopen Vote Review Queue
and was [presented with the option](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/395761)
to vote to reopen [Microcode, is it compulsory?](https://superuser.com/questions/934690/microcode-is-it-compulsory),
which had been edited since it was closed. 
After a few minutes of consideration, I voted to reopen the question. 
Unfortunately, I didn’t keep a journal of exactly what happened,
or video tape it, but ISTR it was something like this:

- I clicked my vote,
  and (after a delay of a few seconds) I got a red box error, something like this,

  [image: An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.]

  only it probably said something about an error when submitting the vote.
- I clicked the ⌧ (`X`-in-box) on the red box
  and clicked refresh in my browser.  After a few seconds, I got an error 523
  (website is offline / origin is unreachable) from my browser. 
  Repeated refreshing got me more 523 errors,
  along with one 522 (connection timed out).
- Eventually (several minutes later) I got back into the review queue,
  only to be [told](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/395761) that the item was no longer reviewable:

  [image: This item is not reviewable.]

  But [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/934690/microcode-is-it-compulsory) was still closed, pending reopen review:

  [image: Microcode, is it compulsory? [on hold] / reopen(4)]

When I looked at the review queue from an anonymous (i.e., logged out) window,
it told me that there was still something in the queue:

[image: Reopen Votes … 1 question]

and when I looked at it from my logged-in window, I got this enigmatic presentation:

[image: Reopen Votes … 0 questions / (filter) by type: *too broad*]

which seemed to suggest (i.e., confirm) that there was something in the queue,
but that it was inaccessible to me.

#### ... and then, while I was typing up this bug report,

I noticed that the question had been reopened, and I was startled to see that my reopen vote had contributed to that result:

[image: **Post Reopened** by Jens Erat, Kevin Panko, Breakthrough, Scott, Twisty]

And, [my user activity page](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott?tab=activity&sort=reviews) shows that I cast a reopen vote,
but doesn’t show that I performed a reopen review on the question. 
And the final gotcha is that
my [reopen vote count(s)](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/stats) didn’t change during the process.

So I guess the questions are:

- Why didn’t the [Reopen Vote Review Queue page](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/395761) show
  that [Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough) and I had voted on the question? 
  (P.S. It *still* doesn’t show it.)
- Why didn’t my reopen vote count statistics go up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you vote to reopen in review, the page sends *two* requests to the server. One request is the actual vote to reopen, which went through and got recorded. The second is the review item submission, which records that you completed the review item and gives you a new one. This second request is where you got the error message.

When you eventually got back in, the system told you that it wasn't reviewable. In reality, that's vague in that it's not reviewable *to you* - because you already have a reopen vote recorded for the question and thus you can't review the question since you can't cast a second reopen vote. There's nothing for you to do.

Unfortunately since you hit an error for the task-reviewed request, that also means the system didn't record that you completed review there. This is an extremely rare occurrence that would happen so infrequently that it's probably not possible (or worthwhile) to fix. These requests are sent near-simultaneously. What are the chances that the connection would die for one but not the other?

As far as Breakthrough's vote - it's possible for users to still cast reopen votes outside of review. Only users who actually cast a vote from within review will show up in the list for the review item.

Comment: Thanks.  I was already guessing most of it, but the bit about the two separate requests was the missing piece of the puzzle.